# Calculating and displaying customer lifetime value histogram with BigQuery and Data Studio

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

Consider a table in Google BigQuery containing purchase records for customer. For the sake of simplicity, let's focus on the following properties:
`customer_id, product_id, amount`

I'd like to create a Google Data Studio report from the above data set showing a customer lifetime value histogram. The customer lifetime value is the sum of `amount` for any given customer. The histogram would show how many customers fall into a certain bucket by their total amount - I would define the buckets like 0-10, 10-20, 20-30 etc. value ranges.

Like this: [image]

Finally, I'd also like to filter the histogram by product_id. When the filter is active, the histogram would show the totals for customers who - at least once - purchased the given product.

As of this moment, I think this is not possible to implement in Datastudio, but I hope I am wrong.

**Things I've tried so far:**

1. Displaying an average customer lifetime value for the whole dataset is easy, via a calculated field in Datastudio as `SUM(amount) / COUNT(customer_id)`
2. For creating a histogram, I don't see any way purely in Data Studio (based on the above data set). I think I need to create a view of the original table, consisting a single row for each customer with the total amount. The bucket assignment could be implemented either in Big Query or in Data Studio with `CASE ... WHEN`.

However, for the final step, i.e. creating a product filter that filters the histogram for those customers who purchased the given product, I have no clue how to approach this.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do a similar reproduction to what you describe but it's not straightforward so I'll try to detail everything. The main idea is to have two data sources from the same table: one contains `customer_id` and `product_id` so that we can filter it while the other one contains `customer_id` and the already calculated `amount_bucket` field. This way we can join it (blend data) on `customer_id` and filter according to `product_id` which won't change the `amount_bucket` calculations.

I used the following script to create some data in BigQuery:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE data_studio.histogram
(
  customer_id STRING,
  product_id STRING,
  amount INT64
);

INSERT INTO data_studio.histogram (customer_id, product_id, amount)
VALUES ('John', 'Game', 60),
       ('John', 'TV', 800),
       ('John', 'Console', 300),
       ('Paul', 'Sofa', 1200),
       ('George', 'TV', 750),
       ('Ringo', 'Movie', 20),
       ('Ringo', 'Console', 250)
;
```

Then I connect directly to the BigQuery table and get the following fields. Data source is called `histogram`:

[image]

We add our second data source (`BigQuery`) using a custom query:

```sql
SELECT
  customer_id,
  CASE
    WHEN SUM(amount) < 500 THEN '0-500'
    WHEN SUM(amount) < 1000 THEN '500-1000'
    WHEN SUM(amount) < 1500 THEN '1000-1500'
    ELSE '1500+'
END
  AS amount_bucket
FROM
  data_studio.histogram
GROUP BY
  customer_id
```

With only the latter we could already do a basic histogram with the following configuration:

[image]

Dimension is `amount_bucket`, metric is `Record count`. I made a `bucket_order` custom field to sort it as lexicographically '1000-1500' comes before '500-1000':

```sql
CASE 
  WHEN amount_bucket = '0-500' THEN 0
  WHEN amount_bucket = '500-1000' THEN 1
  WHEN amount_bucket = '1000-1500' THEN 2
  ELSE 3
END
```

Now we add the `product_id` filter on top and a new chart with the following configuration:

[image]

Note that metric is CTD (Count Distinct) of `customer_id` and the `Blended data` data source is implemented as:

[image]

An example where I filter by `TV` so only `George` and `John` appear but the other products are still counted for the total amount calculation:

[image]

I hope it works for you.

Comment: Brilliant! To reproduce your last screenshot, I had to set the data sources for both tables and the right side chart to the blended data source, and also define the filter over the blended data. Otherwise the filter was not applied to all elements.  But it worked in the end, and this was exactly what I was looking for. Great answer, much appreciated.